# Excel VBA : Trigger Worksheet_Change on manual and non manual change

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined a `Worksheet_Change` sub on a sheet. It works fine.

I just noticed that this is only triggered when the users inputs a value in a cell. When I calculate the sheet, and some cells change values, I'd like it to be called as well, which isn't the case at the moment.

What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way to fix this is to simply add the same event under `Worksheet_Calculate` event. If the routine is large, extract it into it's own sub and simply call it for both events.

Comment: Sounds good, but since I have the Worksheet_Change event on more than one sheet, how to make sure this will call the event of the same sheet ? I'm not sure I can assume it.

Comment: Yes, if you write a sub and put it in a normal module, all your sheet events can call the same sub.